# XAML there's the way to binding the array's index in a Style?

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, styles

is possible to binding the array's index e.g:

```
<Style x:Key="NameButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding Array[{Binding custom property index}]}/>
</Style>
```

Comment: In addition to the link. You could alternatively use a multibinding and multiconverter.

Answer (score 1):

Only if the "index" is specified by a constant like for example `1`:

```
<Style x:Key="NameButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding Array[1]}/>
</Style>
```

You cannot replace `1` in the example above with a dynamic value that is resolved at runtime. If you need this, you'll have to use a converter or expose a property that returns `Array[x]` where `x` represents the dynamic value.